# Java 8 & NIO / Read lines -> collect to entity

Tags: java, io, java-8, nio, java-stream

Need read text file by line and parse each for set according value to object `Entity` members. My entity have next constructor signature:

```
public Entity(int id, String name, double weight)
```

Text file have next content:

```
ID,NAME,WEIGHT
1,Mario,80.2
2,Marco,91.1
...
100,Diego,78.12
```

Using new Java 8: [`Files::readAllLines`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllLines-java.nio.file.Path-) method my solution is very huge:

```
public class CoolApp {

    private static final String SOURCE_FILE = "path/to/txt/file/entities.txt";

    private static final int ID     = 0;
    private static final int NAME   = 1;
    private static final int WEIGHT = 2;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        boolean isHeader = true;

        List<Entity> entities = new ArrayList<>();

        for (String line : Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(SOURCE_FILE))) {
            if (isHeader) {
                isHeader = false;
            }   
            else {
                String[] snippets = line.split(",");

                entities.add(new Entity(
                        Integer.parseInt(snippets[ID]),
                        snippets[NAME],
                        Double.parseDouble(snippets[WEIGHT])
                ));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### How I can to do the same action but use [Collector](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collector.html) to present data in collection of entities some like following ?

```
List<Entity> entities = Files.lines(Paths.get(SOURCE_FILE)).collect(...);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
List<Entity> entities = 
    Files.lines(Paths.get(SOURCE_FILE))
         .skip(1) // skip the header line
         .map(line -> line.split(",")) // transform each line to an array
         .map(snippets -> new Entity(Integer.parseInt(snippets[ID]),
                                     snippets[NAME],
                                     Double.parseDouble(snippets[WEIGHT])) // transform each array to an entity
         .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Note on your code: You should use `true` and `false`, rather than `Boolean.TRUE` and `Boolean.FALSE` (which are instances of Boolean and not primitive boolean values).